# vim : automatically ident when insering a '\' at text-width position

Tags: vim

Using vim I would like to have and auto ident (at text width position) feature when insering a '\' on #define, string and all the others situation when '\' is used to ignore line break.

Here is and exemple (text-width = 78):

```
 /* '\' at maximum text-width */
 #define HELLO "I Think this feature already exist but I wasn't able to find \
               it so far.


 /* usual situation */
 #define HELLO \
         "I Think this feature already exist but I wasn't able ..."


 /* what i would like to have (without identing it myself) */
 #define HELLO                                                               \
         "I Think this feature already exist but I wasn't able ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an automatic solution, but at least you can quickly manually right-justify the continuation character with my [AlignFromCursor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155), which has a `<Leader>ri` mapping that aligns the text right of the cursor at `'textwidth'`.